# insert value in two tables at one submit

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here in my project I want to store the same value in two different tables. When I click on the submit buttons, the value should be stored in both table. 
But here the value is store in second object table function for that table.

Here is my class code:

```
<?php
include("XXXXX.php");
$obj=new add;
$obj2=new add;
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        $Date=$_POST['date'];
        $Amount=$_POST['amount'];
        $user=$_POST['user'];
        $detail=$_POST['detail'];
        $dw=$_POST['deposite'];

        $TotalAmount=$Amount+$last;

    $oiu=$obj->addAmount($Date,$Amount,$user,$a);
    $z=$obj2->addReport($Date,$user,$Amount,$dw,$TotalAmount);
//  $oiu2=$obj->addRs($Date,$Amount);
}
?>
```

functions which I used to store data in database are given below..

```
function addAmount($Date,$Amount,$user,$detail)
    {
        $addCash=$this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `amountcash`(`date`,`amount`,`user`,`detail`)
                                    VALUES(?,?,?,?)") ; 
        $addCash->bind_param("siss",$Date,$Amount,$user,$detail);    
        $addCash->execute();
//  echo "Successful";  
    }

    function addRs($Date,$Amount)
    {
        $addD=$this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `totalamount`(`date`,`amount`) values (?,?,)");
        $addD->bind_param("ss",$Date,$Amount);
        $addD->execute();
    }

    function addReport($Date,$user,$Amount,$dw,$TotalAmount)    
    {
        $addData=$this->conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `amount_flow` (`date`,`user`,`amount`,`detail`,total)values (?,?,?,?,?)');
        $addData->bind_param('ssisi',$Date,$user,$Amount,$dw,$TotalAmount);
        $addData->execute();
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your sql Statement have to end with ; if you want to execute two or more at once

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you add another parameter to your data insertion function called table. for example

```
 function addAmount($Date,$Amount,$user,$detail, $table)
 {
   $addCash=$this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO $table`(`date`,`amount`,`user`,`detail`)
                            VALUES(?,?,?,?)") ; 
   $addCash->bind_param("siss",$Date,$Amount,$user,$detail);    
   $addCash->execute();
   echo "Successful";
  }
```

that way you can do it twice

```
 $oiu=$obj->addAmount($Date,$Amount,$user,$a, "table_name"); //*2
```